# Return Pointer from function with pointer as param

Tags: c, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

I'm reading this book: ["C von A bis Z"](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/c_von_a_bis_z/012_c_zeiger_006.htm).

There is this example.

```
/* ptr14.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* Fehler: Funktion gibt die Adresse
 * einer lokalen Variablen zurück. */
/* [ Error: Function returns the address of a
     a local variable. ] */
// ...

/* Möglichkeit2: Speicher vom Heap verwenden */
/* [ Option2: Use memory from the heap ] */
char *test3(void){
   char *buffer = (char *) malloc(10);
   strcpy(buffer, "testwert");
   return buffer;
}

/* Möglichkeit3: Einen Zeiger als Argument übergeben */
/* [ Option3: Pass a pointer as argument ] */
char *test4(char *ptr){
   char buffer[10];
   ptr = buffer;
   strcpy(buffer, "testwert");
   return ptr;
}
int main(void) {
   char *ptr;

   /* ... */

   ptr = test3();
   printf("test3: %s\n", ptr);
   test4(ptr);
   printf("test4: %s\n", ptr);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm understanding the problem the author is talking about.

**Why the `test4` solution is working?**

If I am understanding correctly, doesn't it

1. allocate `char buffer[10];` on the stack
2. assign the address of the first element of `buffer` to my `ptr` (living in previous scope) `ptr = buffer;`

**my expectation:**

Point with `ptr` on `buffer`should be false, because this scope should be broken/cleaned up.

What is wrong with my thinking?

**EDIT 1**

I changed `test4(ptr);` to `ptr = test4(ptr)` and it still works...

Still don't know why `test4(char* ptr)` is working...

Comment: Which one you refer as 3rd solution?

Comment: `char buffer[10];` the memory stops existing after `}`. You return a pointer to nonexistent memory. I can only guess that in possibility 3 it is expected that `ptr` is a pointer to a valid memory before you call `test4`.

Comment: If the author of that book claims `ptr = buffer;` fixes the problem somehow, you need a new book.

Comment: Also remember that in C all arguments are passed *by value*, i.e. the value is copied into the argument variable. The argument variable is itself local to the function, and all assignments to it will be lost as soon as the variables life-time ends together with the function.

Comment: Hmm, let's keep this open actually because it is from a book.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yeah, because I think the is still no answer of the real question...

Comment: @Wufo yes there is but I want to berate the book.

Comment: ... and the author...

Comment: @Wufo good work, if you read everything with this critical mindset you'll become a stellar C programmer.

Comment: I still think we need a SO "blacklist" with bad books. Hall of Shame kind of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your thinking - you're absolutely correct. Good work, you're now more qualified in the C programming language than the author of the book.

The book is worthless - 3rd revised edition, and it teaches the antiquated version of C from 3 decades ago with horribly broken examples. You just happened to be *lucky* with that `test4`. Putting the address of the first element of array just suppresses the warning in **some** compilers, and the array happened to be in the correct position on the stack and not being overwritten. [But GCC 8.3 isn't fooled by using an intermediate variable.](https://godbolt.org/z/AYn_Km)

---

In the function

```
char *test4(char *ptr){
    char buffer[10];
    ptr = buffer;
    strcpy(buffer, "testwert");
    return ptr;
}
```

using the `ptr` within the function does in no way affect the pointer outside the function. It worked in the original example because the `ptr` was *still* pointing to the value returned from `test3`, which was allocated from heap. When you replace it with `ptr = test4(ptr);` you'll get wholly undefined behaviour, as `ptr` now points to a variable past its lifetime. And when undefined behaviour happens, then the program might do anything, including ([C11 3.4.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p1)):

> [...] ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results [...]

with "unpredictable results" including the possibility of it working "as intended".

---

The previous bulletin point lists one of the options as

> - [Sie verwenden] einen beim Aufruf der Funktion als Argument übergebenen Puffer [...]

i.e. *[You'll use] a buffer passed as an argument into the function*. For this option, `test4` should read

```
// use the **array** starting from *ptr
char *test4(char *ptr){
    // use a **different** string here so that you can verify
    // that it actually *works* (max 9 characters!)
    strcpy(ptr, "testval 4");
    return ptr;
}
```

or even perhaps

```
void test4(char *ptr){
    strcpy(ptr, "testval 4");
}
```

with documentation telling that prior to calling this function `ptr` should point to an array of at least 10 `char`s.

Comment: Upped. And it's also an example of a broader thing. Lack of a diagnostic does not mean lack of a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will save the topic as "undefined behavior" and will not do it like in test4 (char * ptr) ... ^^

Comment: With some Google translate, this section is actually all about warning the programmer about returning local variables allocated on the stack. "Möglichkeit3" is simply sloppily written - they just copy/pasted the erroneous function `test1`. Guess nobody proof-read the book.

Comment: Btw please note that the fixed `char* test4(char *ptr)` will only work if main is changed to `char buf[10]; ... test4(buf);`. In the author's example, we have `char* ptr` in main which won't work even with the fixed `test4`.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *test4(char *ptr) {
    char buffer[10];
    ptr = buffer;
    strcpy(buffer, "teswert");
    return ptr;
}
```

This code doesn't do anything else than returning an invalid pointer. Your understanding is correct, the stack pointer returned is invalid and shouldn't be read.

The reason why this "works" is because that pointer isn't actually used.

```
test4(ptr);
```

A copy of the pointer is passed and the return value is discarded, so it does nothing. The printed text is from `test3`. Case in point, you can change that one `"testwert"` and the print you get is the exact same, and if you change the one in `test3` it changes both prints. So in other words, the book makes a mistake and hides it with another mistake, and then it doesn't notice all the mistakes because of how poorly it tests the code (if it wouldn't be `"testwert"` four times, the errors would be apparent, and of course any compiler worth its salt will issue a warning).

I recommend trashing that book.

---

With the edited version of `ptr = test4(ptr)` it's undefined behavior, so anything might happen. This includes printing the expected output, printing rubbish, crashing the program or worse.

Comment: @Wufo now it's just undefined behavior, which means it might or might not work. For me on MSVC it doesn't work (it prints rubbish like in the first case).